# What is the "Hotkey Enable" button supposed to be?

Tags: retropie, emulation

I have installed RetroPie on a new Raspberry Pi and went to set up a controller. After pressing all the buttons as requested, I was prompted to select something for "Hotkey Enable". What is this supposed to represent? I'm all out of buttons on my controller, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do when prompted for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hold down any key to skip it if you don’t have a spare button.

If you had a dedicated hot key button, it would take the place of “select” for activating the emulator shortcuts while in a game (such an quitting back to EmulationStation or opening the retroarch menu).

Comment: On first launch, I assigned this to the Xbox button on an Xbox One controller (over USB) and it doesn't seem to do anything in-game. Is there setup beyond assigning a button in the controller setup?

Comment: I started mashing a few buttons. I did get the Xbox+Start to exit the running game, which would be the former Select+Start shortcut. So, there might be new shortcuts out there defining how to use the new Hotkey button for the prior shortcuts.

Answer (score 12):

As [MDMarra suggested](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76925/19517), you can skip this assignment by holding any button. If you do have a dedicated button like the Xbox button or PS button on your controller, you can assign it to make some of the emulator shortcuts use it.

Here are the shortcuts I've seen so far:

- Hotkey+Start = exit emulator
- Hotkey+Right shoulder = save state
- Hotkey+Left shoulder = load saved state
- Hotkey+Left = decrease current saved state slot number
- Hotkey+Right = increase current saved state slot number
- Hotkey+X = quick menu (with access to most of these other items)
- Hotkey+B = reset game